# select multiple rows from a stored procedure using entity data model

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework, ado.net

I want a stored procedure to return multiple rows and i am using entity data model. Also i want to retrieve the value of columns of all the rows given as output.

I had done this thing using `SqlDataReader`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection`.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select leave_details,LID,from_date,to_date from LeaveTable where E_ID=1 and from_date<@toDate and to_date>@fromDate", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@toDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date);
cmd.Parameters["@toDate"].Value = to_date;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@fromDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date);
cmd.Parameters["@fromDate"].Value = from_date;
con.Open();

obj = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

And i can traverse through rows using `obj.read()`.

And i can read value of particular column using

```
leave_id = (int)obj.GetValue(1);
```

How can i get the same thing done by a stored procedure and creating a Function Import using Entity Data Model??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several steps to do this I believe this is by far the best tutorial to achieve this that can be found  online

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx

you basically have to create a new complex type since you are selecting from several tables I believe this tutorial has an example on how to do this. basically you will return a set of values in a list and then you can read each value/object from alist

Comment: I found this one more useful - http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/a-big-step-for-stored-procedures-in-ef4/

Answer (score 0):

you can add store procedure as function import in  entity framework object model, while adding it will ask you return type... so it can generate complex custom entity. while communication with store procedure it will fetch data from entity fretwork & add it in custom entity so you will get multiple rows from table & one more point when you will create object of entity then you will get name of function by which we are are set .ToLIst() to its calaling end so it will return you list of results set.

i.e

Entity Teamwork  :   abcentity

create object of entity :   abventity abc = new abcentity();

call SP function :   var Result = abc.SPCall(parmaeters).tolist();

in result you will get list of result from store procedure